# How to initialize a nested anonymous array double in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, nested, anonymous, constructor-overloading

I have a constructor that expects a nested array of doubles like this:

```
public class Thing {

    public Thing (double[][] doubles) {
    }
}
```

I would like to overload the constructor with a default constructor that takes no arguments like this:

```
    public Thing () {
        this(/* TODO */);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to nest a new one-dimensional double array into another two dimensional double array. That way, you can initialize the inner, one-dimensional one manually and the outer two dimensional one with it.

```
    public Thing () {
        this(new double[][]{new double[]{1}});
    }
```

You can also initialize more than one double:

```
        this(new double[][]{new double[]{1, 2, 3}});
```

or even:

```
        this(new double[][]{new double[]{1, 2, 3},
                            new double[]{4, 5, 6}});
```

Comment: Or ``new double[0][0]`` or size you want in the brackets.